# How to generate Intermediate files in Haxe?

Tags: haxe

I am searching for how to save the intermediate files generated after preproccesing, compiling and several other steps as in C (where we use a flag like `--save-temps`).

I am considering the case where you run the program directly without converting it into any other language.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer after going through one of the official discord servers,

```
haxe -v -D dump=pretty --main Main --interp
```

on a file named `Main.hx`.

`-v` generates verbose information.

`-D dump=pretty` dumps information such as intermediate files.

`--interp` runs in intrepret mode without converting it into any other language.